# Telerik RadCalendar Internet Explorer error

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, telerik, rad-controls

I'm using the Telerik RadCalendar control and when I try to navigate through a day (click in day in calendar) in the calendar i can't in IE. In Chrome and Firefox works ok but not in IE.

Any suggestions? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Which IE is that? What is your RadControls version? Does the problem occur with the latest?
Try their demos and see, if they work fine, compare your setup with the demo and find the difference: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx.

Also, look for (and resolve) any JavaScript errors you may have.
If you are having the problem in a newer IE, it may be an error from your .NET 4 framework: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-12-19/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11.